# Django allauth get full linkedin details

Tags: django, django-allauth

Using django-allauth with linkedin however can't get full profile details from profile of the user.

in the settings file

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = { 
        'stackexchange': { 'SITE': 'stackoverflow' },
        'linkedin':{'SCOPE': ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']}
    }
```

and on the account I check extra_data and get

```
{u'firstName': u'Samuel', u'lastName': u'Muiruri', u'pictureUrls': {u'_total': 1, u'values': [u'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_C1AR7HY-6mvzKOYWkCPzody-62WvzgOW5_7nWd8yaZHnlyuFFiKcIigGyxn']}, u'pictureUrl': u'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_dCvykIHSymsQZ-MUdbc_kWwSpuuw4-4UI5TikeHriWZsFnfR5k5KoHyO-G2vUzJBHTBCwfVnu3gN', u'emailAddress': u'muiruri.samuel@gmail.com', u'publicProfileUrl': u'https://www.linkedin.com/in/samuel-muiruri-a5235532', u'id': u'_xLBtzYkuK'}
```

on linkedin dev oauth page I've selected email and `r_basicprofile`

**UPDATE**

The available options for linked in oauth 2 [image]

and given rights when login in via linkedin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If on the linkedin page you’ve only given your app access to `r_basicprofile` you can’t get `r_fullprofile`.  To give your app access to the full profile, give it access to `r_fullprofile` on the linked in oauth page.

From [the LinkedIn docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)

> All REST API calls require certain permissions to be granted from the LinkedIn member before they can be made.  This system ensures that members are made aware of what an application could possibly access or do on their behalf before approving it.
>
> The permissions that members are asked to grant are determined based on the permissions you tell your application to ask for during the OAuth 2.0 authentication process.  They can be specified within the LinkedIn application configuration itself, or they can be explicitly requested using the scope argument during the authorization step of the OAuth 2.0 process.

Comment: don't think that's the case updated the question, the available options for oauth is only basic profile, edited to the same name on the settings file and on login it does state "and current positions"